# How to install Nagios on one VM to check the specific stats of another VM(client side) without using Apache and PHP?

Tags: centos, nagios

How to install Nagios on one VM to check the specific stats of another VM(client-side) without using Apache and PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can install nagios [agent](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details) and config nagios server to ask agent about specific check. On the agent side you should config shell script to check specific parameter